# Bug: page 9 and 10 of the questions ranked by votes show wrong questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions?page=10&sort=votes shows questions with a score ranging from 6 to -1, while page 9 suddenly goes from 46 to 27 votes and sharply down from there. Page 11 starts again at 46 votes.

I reproduced this using Chrome 36 and IE11. I've also tried it using a few proxies and the problem remains. I sort of remember a similar issue when I was archive binging on Stack Overflow over a year ago.

Comment: We did have a search/indexing issue earlier today, but that's been fixed. It is probably related to this.

Comment: @Oded That might be why I had it. I just reported it because I thought it is something you would want to know as a developer. Next time I get that bug, should I update this question, or should I make a new one? And what should I include immediately?

Comment: A new question would be best - and what to include depends on the bug... For visual issues, a screen shot is useful and if the issue may not be immediately obvious, red freehand circles around the problem area ;) For browser interaction oddities, adding your browser, OS and if you see any JavaScript/Network errors in the browser developer tools are also handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, all of page 9 is all 23 votes with some 22 votes at the bottom, page 10 is 22 votes except for a couple at the bottom on 21 votes, and page 11 is all 21 votes with some 20 votes at the bottom.

I have tested just now on Chrome 36 and IE 8 (I know - I just had an image with IE 8 ready)

You must have something set oddly. Are you on Unanswered, or one of the other tabs?

Comment: I'll add screenshots. Or not. Seems like it's no longer there. I encountered this issue both times when I was working my way back from the first page, opening a few questions on each page in a new window along the way, but I can no longer reproduce it.